# Web browser on OpenELEC

Tags: kodi, openelec, web-browsers

I have a model B raspberry pi running OpenELEC 4.0.7. I want to use a web browser using the raspberry pi and OpenELEC. Is there an addon for OpenELEC that allows a web browser to be run?

I have seen some posts regarding Chromium for xbmc and Advanced Launcher but I have not been able to get these working.

http://openelec.tv/forum/chromium-browser/69999-chromium-browser-added-to-unofficial-repository

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unoffical Chromium port isn't avaliable for the Raspberry Pi. And author wrote about it:

> There will be NO RPi build. please dont ask me to do it.